# How to perform an action every couple of seconds?

Tags: javascript

Can someone quickly and simply explain to me how to perform an action every couple of seconds using

```
var timeOut = setTimeout(FunctionName, 5000);
```

I want to run a function every 5 seconds.

Comment: I think you want setInterval and not setTimeout.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9WkRw/ this will update every second. This is on domready with jquery.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you asked for a method using `setTimeout`:

```
function doStuff() {
   console.log("hello!");
   setTimeout(doStuff, 5000);
}
setTimeout(doStuff, 5000);
```

But it would probably be better to use `setInterval`:

```
function doStuff() {
   console.log("hello!");
}
setInterval(doStuff, 5000);
```

Comment: What console.log does exactly?

Comment: It prints whatever you tell it to print to the console (press F12 in newer browsers to open the console).

Comment: +1 for the example using `setTimeout` -- this is often the better way of meeting this need.

Comment: What is the different between setTimeout and setInterval and in what cases are you better off to use either of those?

Comment: @Pete - There is a great explanation of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Answer (score 2):

Just put `setTimeout` at the end inside your function, with a call to itself - like a delayed tail-recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval`:

```
var timeOut = setInterval(nextNotice, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFunction = function() { 
     //Do stuff
     AnotherFunction();
};

var timeOut = setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, when a button is clicked, the input field will start to count (for ever), starting at 0.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var c = 0;
      var t;
      var timer_is_on = false;

      function timedCount() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
        c = c + 1;
        t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
      }

      function doTimer() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
          timer_is_on = true;
          timedCount();
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()">
      <input type="text" id="txt" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [W3Schools is not a great resource](http://w3fools.com/).  If you are linking an article on another site, please also summarise it here.

Comment: But the resource has a perfect example:

Comment: No, it has a functional example. There are numerous problems with that bit of code that make it a poor example (use of a number as a boolean, use of a string with `setTimeout`, no actual invocation of the code, meaningless variable names).

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
        {
setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
}
function nextNotice()
{
// do stuff 
setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Why setTimeout is used twice?

Comment: true, you can just call nextNotice() in document ready function if you want the messages/actions to appear/process straight away, rather than waiting the set time.