# Click on the play button every 3 secs with user script - Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a script which click on the play / pause button every 3 secs. The video is in the google drive and I'd like to make a Tampermonkey script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Drive video
// @description 
// @author 
// @version 1.0
// @match *drive.google.com*
// @match https://drive.google.com*
// ==/UserScript==

var playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button.ytp-button");

// To videos variables
    function playOrPause() {
        playButton.click();
    }

setInterval(playOrPause(), 3000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(playOrPause, 3000);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - perform an action every couple of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909692/jquery-perform-an-action-every-couple-of-seconds)

Comment: Also read [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: What error is it throwing ?

Comment: You might wanna use `querySelector` like `document.querySelector(".ytp-play-button.ytp-button")`

Comment: Is it resolved ?

Answer (score -1):

the main issue in your code is to pass function reference **playOrPause** not call it **playOrPause()**

```
  function playOrPause() {
        playButton.click();
        setTimeout(playOrPause, 3000);
    }

setTimeout(playOrPause, 3000);
```

or

```
function playOrPause() {
        playButton.click();
    }

setInterval(playOrPause, 3000);
```

Comment: Why would you add another setInterval? Will have hundreds of interval timers running after a while

Comment: I dislike answers with *«Try this»* as the only explanation.